# How to get duration of audio from service and set to seekbar item in adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to play an audio using service and update seekbar item in adapter. But I am unable to get duration of audio from service. Also when scrolling recyclerview, more than one item view is updated instead of updating currently playing seekbar item. I have tried below code.

```
public class LocalService extends Service {

boolean mBound = false;

private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
private String path = "";
private int timer;

private static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
// Random number generator

/**
 * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
 * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
 */
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {

    public LocalService getService() {
        // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods

        return LocalService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return mBinder;
}

/**
 * method for clients
 */
public int getTotalTime() {

    return mediaPlayer.getDuration();
}

public int getDuration() {
    // Log.v("player duration",timer+"");
    try {
        if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            Log.v("playing", (mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000) + "");
            return mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
        } else {
            //Log.v("not playing", (mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000) + "");
            return 0;
        }
    }catch (IllegalStateException i)
    {
        i.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }

}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    try {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void setAudio(String path)
{
    try {

            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);



    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void playAudio() {
    Log.v("audio path", path);

    try {

        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                mediaPlayer.start();
                timer=mediaPlayer.getDuration();

                Log.v("total timer1",timer+"");

            }
        });


        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                timer=0;
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                //mediaPlayer.release();
            }
        });



    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void unbindService(ServiceConnection conn) {
    super.unbindService(conn);

    mediaPlayer.reset();
    mediaPlayer.release();
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mediaPlayer.reset();
    mediaPlayer.release();

}
```

Service is started from adapter constructor.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, LocalService.class);
    mContext.bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

player item click in recycler adpater

```
    vhItemHolder.playPauseImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                currentlyPlayingPosition = position;

                if (mBound) {

                    Log.v("service","bound");

                    //Make sure you update Seekbar on UI thread
                    mService.setAudio(audioDirectory+messageArrayList.get(position).getmMediaValue());

                    mPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
                    try {
                        mPlayer.setDataSource(audioDirectory+messageArrayList.get(position).getmMediaValue());
                        mPlayer.prepareAsync();
                        vhItemHolder.seekBar.setMax(mPlayer.getDuration());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    mService.playAudio();

                    Log.v("duration",(mService.getTotalTime())+"");

                    vhItemHolder.seekBar.setMax(mService.getTotalTime());

                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(null);

                    mHandler=new Handler();

                    ((DoctorActivity)mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            num = mService.getDuration();
                            Log.v("progress",num+"");
                            vhItemHolder.seekBar.setProgress((num));
                            vhItemHolder.runningTimerTextView.setText(convertMilliToMinutes((long)mService.getDuration()));

                            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 50);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.v("service","not bound");
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your adapter class:
You are making a new object of MediaPlayer (mPlayer) in  viewHolder's playPauseImageView's onClickListener and calling setDataSource() method on it which sets data source for this local mPlayer object not to the mediaPlayer object of your LocalService class.

Calling mService.playAudio() and mService.getDuration() methods access your LocalService class' mediaPlayer object for which setDataSource() method is not called yet, hence must be returning wrong duration and unable to play.

You should make a change in your adapter class like below:

```
vhItemHolder.playPauseImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            currentlyPlayingPosition = position;

            if (mBound) {

                Log.v("service","bound");

                //Make sure you update Seekbar on UI thread
                mService.setAudio(audioDirectory+messageArrayList.get(position).getmMediaValue());

                mPlayer = mService.mediaPlayer;// or mPlayer = LocalService.mediaPlayer; as being static object.
    //rather new MediaPlayer();
                try {
                    mPlayer.setDataSource(audioDirectory+messageArrayList.get(position).getmMediaValue());
                    mPlayer.prepareAsync();
                    vhItemHolder.seekBar.setMax(mPlayer.getDuration());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mService.playAudio();

                Log.v("duration",(mService.getTotalTime())+"");

                vhItemHolder.seekBar.setMax(mService.getTotalTime());

                mHandler.removeCallbacks(null);

                mHandler=new Handler();

                ((DoctorActivity)mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        num = mService.getDuration();
                        Log.v("progress",num+"");
                        vhItemHolder.seekBar.setProgress((num));
                        vhItemHolder.runningTimerTextView.setText(convertMilliToMinutes((long)mService.getDuration()));

                        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 50);
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                Log.v("service","not bound");
            }
```